# React Testing Library: Disabled attribute not being removed when state changes

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

So I have a form field component to render 2 select fields. When a user selects a value from the first select, then the second select becomes enabled (it's disabled by default).

I have testIDs set on each select: the first is typeSelect

I'm doing something like this for testing:

```
  userEvent.selectOptions(screen.getByTestId('firstSelect'), ['Yes']);
  expect(screen.getByTestId('firstSelect_option_Yes').selected).toBe(true);
  expect(screen.getByTestId('secondSelect').toBeEnabled();
```

However, the secondSelect continues to show that it has the `disabled = ''` attribute.

Is this a bug? I read about the node element being bound, but it seems odds that I can't test the disabled being removed behavior, as it works just fine in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Where and when it is showing for you that disabled=''? It might be a output for your page initial state.

You can test weather it is disabled or not, with `expect(myField).toHaveProperty('disabled', false);`

This might answer some of doubts: https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom/discussions/325